# When adding CSS in civimail (under source) getting an error when trying to see or send test

Tags: civimail, css

Trying to use my own custom html e-mail in CiviMail with custom CSS in it (specifically to optimize on mobile).
When I have the CSS stylesheet info on top I cannot send a test email or preview in HTML. when I click either of them I get Error
"Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"
How can I get around this?

Comment: I am still having this issue on WordPress
 the error I'm getting in the chrome console is "POST https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/rest 500"jquery.min.js?r=p6mna:4 
Anyone know what this can be? or how to fix it?

Comment: When testing the same Email on Drupal I did not have that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed or for me was creating a css file and copying the style sheet into that file and referencing it as a external style sheet in the html (instead of having it in the actual email)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add your style sheet inside {literal} when adding stylesheet in Message template. For example

```
{literal}
<style>
 your code
</style>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm just getting {literal}{/literal} in my email message now.

Comment: I was wondering if civimail only works with CSS inline?

Comment: Try adding the setting in civicrm.setting.php described here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty

Comment: @Demerit I think that's something totally different. Smarty is enavled and used but that does not have to do with this AFAIK.